# Invalid points in NMDS plot

Tags: vegan

While using metaMDS function from vegan package to create NMDS plot in R, I have 10 samples in the data but in my NMDS plot, there are only 7 points. Do you know why that might happen?
I tried to see if there's anything wrong with the codes, but seems like maybe something else is wrong here.

[Datafiles](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_oXqvT_ICWkbeHJAGk5Hn_ZynM3uRNLP?usp=drive_link)

```
    beta_gene <- read.table("normalized_gene_counts_CvsM_3.csv", check.names = F, header = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names = 1)
    beta_gene <- t(beta_gene)
    beta.env <- read.table("EO_meta_CvsM_3.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    data_gene_dist <- vegdist(beta_gene, method = "bray")

    #NMDS ordination
    beta_gene_ord<-metaMDS(data_gene_dist, distance = "bray")
    plot(beta_gene_ord, type="none")
    colall=c(5,6)
    points(beta_gene_ord, display = "sites", pch=20, col=colall[as.numeric(as.factor(beta.env$Treatment))])
```

Comment: where is your [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry. This is the very first time I am posting questions. Just edited.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the missing points do not have the same values for the variables you computed dissimilarities for or have the same dissimilarities to other points?

Comment: Easiest way to see that you really have 10 points is to use `scores()` to extract the coordinates of points. Theres should be 10 rows even with duplicated coordinates.

Comment: Yes, there are 10 rows. But, some of them have almost similar values for NMDS1. Is that the reason?